Confluent BigQuery sink connector is not creating nor updating tables properly when run in AWS MSK, but will work locally when running in Docker
I am running the Confluent BQ sink connector both in AWS MSK, and in Docker running Kafka Connect in distributed mode.
In distributed mode on my machine, the connector will run fine. It creates a new table for each topic without any problems, and will write to existing tables as well.
But when I run the exact same connector (same config) in AWS MSK, I get an error:
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b] org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.RetriableException: Failed to retrieve information for table GenericData{classInfo=[datasetId, projectId, tableId], {datasetId=dataset_name, tableId=new-topic-name}}
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkTask.retrieveTable(BigQuerySinkTask.java:405)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1134)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkTask.retrieveCachedTable(BigQuerySinkTask.java:390)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkTask.getRecordTable(BigQuerySinkTask.java:235)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkTask.writeSinkRecords(BigQuerySinkTask.java:268)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkTask.put(BigQuerySinkTask.java:321)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:586)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:329)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:238)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b] Caused by: com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Error getting access token for service account: connect timed out
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:115)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getTable(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:286)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$18.call(BigQueryImpl.java:761)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$18.call(BigQueryImpl.java:758)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:103)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getTable(BigQueryImpl.java:757)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkTask.retrieveTable(BigQuerySinkTask.java:395)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  ... 16 more
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: connect timed out
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:444)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:157)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:145)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:603)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:91)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions$1.initialize(HttpTransportOptions.java:159)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:91)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:404)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getTable(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:284)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  ... 23 more
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b] Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:305)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:509)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:604)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:373)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:207)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1367)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1342)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:441)
[Worker-038a2275014ff9b9b]  ... 34 more

Here is my connector config:
{
"name": "connector-name",
"config": {
  "connector.class": "com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkConnector",
  "allowNewBigQueryFields": "true",
  "allowBigQueryRequiredFieldRelaxation": "true",
  "autoCreateTables": "true",
  "tasks.max": "2",
  "topics": "existing-topic-name, new-topic-name",
  "project": "gcp-project-name",
  "defaultDataset": "dataset_name",
  "keyfile": "/etc/kafka/secrets/gcp-cred.key",
  "schemaRetriever": "com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.retrieve.IdentitySchemaRetriever",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "<my schema registry URL goes here>",
  "value.converter.enhanced.avro.schema.support": "true",
  "schema.registry.url": "<my schema registry URL goes here>",
  "offsets.retention.minutes": 2880,
  "auto.offset.reset": "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit": "true",
  "isolation.level": "read_committed"
}
}

update: I have tried setting allowBigQueryRequiredFieldRelaxation to false and it now works, but I don't quite understand why. I also haven't done enough testing to determine if this fully fixes the issue.
another update if anyone else runs into this issue in the future: I had the issue come up again after making the recent change directly above this line. Then I set "allowSchemaUnionization": "true" and it appears to work again.
